# nonlinear optimization : restricting search space to "limited" preselected value

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

My function is nonlinear with respect to a scalar \alpha .

However, the calculation of objective function is very time consuming, making optimization also very time consuming. Also, I have to do it for 1/2 millon voxels (3d equivalent of pixels).  I plan to do it using “lsqnonlin” of matlab. However, this question is purely mathematical.

Rather than optimizing over all possible real values, I plan to search over preselected 60 values. Since I can pre-calculate value for these, it would be very fast. In other words, I need to restrict search space.

I can not do grid search over preselected value as I plan to perform spatial smoothing in 3D. Some guidance would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Dushyant

Comment: this is a math forum, so post equations. Regards,

Comment: I'm not clear what you are proposing.  If you evaluate the objective function at "preselected 60 values", then of course it is easy to find which are minimum or maximum among that finite set of results.  But what do you expect "spatial smoothing" to accomplish?